# Waiting for one element or another in Selenide

Tags: selenium-webdriver

How do you wait for one or another element in Selenide? In Selenium3 I've manage to do this by using this code:

```
    public void waitForOneorOtherElement(SelenideElement element1, SelenideElement element2) {
        waitForIgnoreStale(ExpectedConditions.or(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element1), ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(element2)), defaultWait);
    }
```

But what would be the Selenide equivelent of this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Selenide, you can use the `$$` method to find multiple elements and the `waitUntil` method to wait for any one of them to be present. Here's an example of how you can wait for either one of two elements in Selenide:

```
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.*;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;

public void waitForOneorOtherElement(SelenideElement element1, SelenideElement element2) {
    $$x(element1.getXPath() + "|" + element2.getXPath())
        .shouldHaveSize(1)
        .waitUntil(visible, defaultWait);
}
```

In this example, we use the `$$x` method to find elements using XPath, and concatenate the XPaths of both elements using the `|` operator to find either one of them. The resulting list of elements should have a size of 1, which means either one of the elements is present. Then we use the `waitUntil` method to wait for that element to become visible, with a timeout of `defaultWait` (which you can define as a constant).

Note that you can replace the `$$x` method with any other method that returns a list of elements in Selenide, such as `$$` (for CSS selectors) or `findAll` (for Selenide conditions).

I hope this helps! For more information, you can refer to the Selenide documentation on finding elements and waiting for conditions to be met.

---

**Edit:**

The `shouldHaveSize(1)` method is not required in this case, as we are just looking for the presence of either element, and not specifically checking for the size of the resulting list of elements.

Regarding the use of `getXPath()` method, it is not a method in Selenide, and I apologize for the error in my previous answer. You can use `By.xpath()` method instead to get the XPath of the element.

Here's an updated example code snippet that should work:

```
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Condition.*;
import static com.codeborne.selenide.Selenide.*;

public void waitForOneOrOtherElement(SelenideElement element1, SelenideElement element2) {
    $$(By.xpath(element1.getXPath() + " | " + element2.getXPath()))
        .waitUntil(visible, defaultWait);
}
```

In this example, we are using `By.xpath()` method to get the XPath of each element, and then concatenate them using the `|` operator to form the XPath expression that matches either one of them. We then use the resulting expression to find the elements using `$$(...)` method, and wait until at least one of them is visible using `waitUntil(visible, defaultWait)` method.

I hope this updated answer helps you resolve your issue. If you have any further questions or concerns, please don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: Hey, I tried this but it doesn't seem to work? shouldHaveSize(1) and getXpath() did not work. Even when I directly paste the Xpaths in I get issues with the shouldHaveSize(1).


$$x("//main[@id='maincontent']/section/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/section/ul/li" + "|" +"//main[@id='maincontent']/section/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/section/div[2]").shouldHaveSize(1).waitUntil(Condition.visible);

Comment: Hope the edit helps you resolve your issue.